# group by and count(*) after join

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, count, left-join

Following code joins a table full of dates with a table which have registries on 'X' date.

```
SELECT
  d.date as 'fecha',
  IFNULL(q.name,0) as 'nombre'
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN quarantine_registry q
ON d.date = q.change_date where d.date <= CURDATE() order by d.date desc
```

Output would be something like:

```
fecha - nombre

2020-09-08 - 0  
2020-09-07 - ggg
2020-09-07 - dwdw  
2020-09-07 - test  
2020-09-07 - Uuu  
2020-09-07 - aaaacdac  
2020-09-07 - asaaws  
2020-09-07 - dwdwdw  
2020-09-07 - vsed  
2020-09-07 - ppp  
2020-09-07 - test  
2020-09-07 - Ygg  
2020-09-07 - Cc  
2020-09-07 - 0      
...
```

**I forgot: I only want to join the registries in quarantine_registry which have change_type = 'add'**

How can I do it to count the number of registries each date has and group by date?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT()` after joining, just like you say in the title.

Comment: I forgot: I only want to join the registries in quarantine_registry which have change_type = 'add'

Comment: Add that to the `ON` condition: `ON d.date = q.change_date AND q.change_type = 'add'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT d.date AS 'fecha',
       count(id) AS registeries_count
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN quarantine_registry q ON d.date = q.change_date
WHERE d.date <= CURDATE()
GROUP BY d.date
ORDER BY d.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I do it to count the number of registries each date has and group by date?

You seem to want aggregation:

```
select d.date, count(q.change_date) cnt
from dates d
left join quarantine_registry q on d.date = q.change_date 
where d.date <= current_date
group by d.date
```

Basically, the query starts from the dates table, and attempts to bring the corresponding registry rows. Then the dataset is grouped by date, and we count how many rows were found in the registry (if no row matched, you get a count of `0`).

Comment: I forgot: I only want to join the registries in quarantine_registry which have change_type = 'add'

Comment: @ÒscarFuentes: just add that condition to the `left join`, like:  `... left join quarantine_registry q on d.date = q.change_date and q.change_type = 'add'`

Answer (score 0):

I guess null does not count

```
SELECT
  d.date as 'fecha',
  count(*)
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN quarantine_registry q
ON d.date = q.change_date where d.date <= CURDATE()
where q.name is not null
group by d.date
order by d.date desc
```